# Switch off Tap-Highlight-Color on Android 4.4 WebView component

Tags: android, css, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat

We use the css property `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);` to switch off the border around a touch selection in the WebView. But this seems to no longer work with the new Chromium WebView component in Android 4.4. Anyone an idea how to switch off the tap highlight color in the new WebView component?

Comment: Are you also using -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; in conjunction with your rgba value?

Comment: No, is this required? Always just use the only line above, which works fine in the old WebView. Will test adding transparent.

Comment: Didn't help, in fact added "transparent" added a strange hovering effect to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
outline: 0;
```

try using both.

Comment: Thanks, without the outline it doesn't work for me (Chrome webview, API 22)