# How can I avoid unicode buttons in the Android webview?

Tags: android, html, css, unicode, android-webview

I am using Unicode arrows in an Android app that uses webview to display HTML5 pages.

This is the sample markup for the arrows:

```
<a href="#s003" class="HLink Nav">&#9664;</a>
<a href="#s005" class="HLink Nav NavR">&#9654;</a>
```

However, the arrows are displayed inside a button as shown in the screenshot. The `HLink` and `Nav` classes only modify the colour and positioning. No border or background is used.

[image: Android Unicode Arrow]

When I open the same HTML in a browser, the arrows display fine.

How can I avoid this behavior of the Android web view?

Comment: Have you tried using a "text style" variation selector after the character? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29669091/596219

Comment: There is no variant for these characters in this case...

Comment: There are... search for `25C0` in [StandardizedVariants.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/7.0.0/ucd/StandardizedVariants.txt). Or do you mean that the selectors have no effect?

Comment: No, it didn't have any effect. But maybe I am not writing it right. Do you have a sample of how it would be written for the links posted?

Comment: Put `&#xFE0E;` after the characters.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in reply. Adding the characters has no effect. Problem is still there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch off Tap-Highlight-Color on Android 4.4 WebView component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813648/switch-off-tap-highlight-color-on-android-4-4-webview-component)